# Download Full directory from PHP

Tags: php, html, file, directory, download

a simple question that's freaking me out. I created an upload zone in which files are uploaded to a folder that was dynamically created by an mkdir. But if I wanted to download that folder how do I proceed? I don't necessarily need it to be made .zip just for me to be readable and that the files inside it are intact.

I tried pointing directly at the folder with the following href but it does not work.

```
<td align="center"><a href="/home/rptcanti/public_html/rpt/produzione/UPLOAD/<?php echo $arrayTicket1[$x][0] ?>"><b>Scarica Bolle</b></b></a></td>
```

Comment: If you don't want to download each file individually you will need to bundle them into a single file one way or another, with `.zip` being the most familiar to users.

Comment: You have to run a script in PHP to zip the files and then offer the zip for download. Http has no concept of folders and therefore you cannot download a whole folder directly

Comment: ty for reply you have some example for me ? ty